# android offline mode - LRU cache or Realm database

Tags: android, caching, realm, offlineapps, lru

I am working on an android project where I need to save my json files to implement `offline mode`.

According to my research I can use `LRu cache` or `Realm database`

Still confused which one to use or is there a better way to implement offline mode for mob app ?

Comment: Realm is a good option, but you need to look into Realm Platform in addition to Realm Database. The former is the back-end that takes care of syncing your local and remote data

Answer (score 0):

caching your data might not be the best option to go for in this case, i think using database will be the best option,
you can use realm database or best yet room database you can follow the benchmark test for Android persistence libraries here [Android-ORM-benchmark](https://github.com/AlexeyZatsepin/Android-ORM-benchmark) 
 and read more from android developer page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean by LRU cache, the [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache) in Android or generally the technique of evicting least used items.

Anyway, you are comparing very two different things here.

I will assume that when you mention offline mode, you need your data to survive you app's process being killed for any reason.

So you users would come back to your application in a day or two, and the persisted data would still be there.

For offline persistence you have multiple options

- SharedPreferences (might not be best idea for cache)
- Files either on internal or external storage, might be faster than implementing a database if your data is not huge
- SQLite database

If you have lots of data and need some CRUD operations, DB is probably the way to go, there are lots of ORMs on Android, Realms is certainly one of them, but to name a few more.

- OrmLite
- GreenDAO
- Realm
- Room (made by Android team)
  There are also many more, just Google "Android ORMs"

Hope that helps!